# is there a way to use PHPUnit to make sure the floating point numbers being compared are exactly equal?

Tags: unit-testing, floating-point, phpunit

For example, the following test passes on my system, despite the numbers NOT being equal.

```
$this->assertEquals(17.2222222222000, 17.2222222222999);
```

Is there a way to make PHPUnit throw an error even if ONE digit is off?

My version is PHPUnit 6.4.3

As to why I'm trying to get exact values, is I am testing a mathematical unit conversion library, to where precision is deemed important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to specify the *delta* as [per the documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html):

```
$this->assertEquals(17.2222222222000, 17.2222222222999, '', 0.00000001);
```

Where that last number represents the +/- accuracy you're willing to tolerate.

Comment: thanks.  it seems like the way I have it configured now, PHP handles precision till about `0.0000000000001`

Comment: Why would the problem occur in the first place, and why would this fix it? First, the documentation you refer to describes `assertEquals` with “assertEquals(float $expected, float $actual[, string $message = '', float $delta = 0])”. I presume that “= 0” means the default value of `delta` is 0. So why would the `assertEquals` in the question allow the test to pass instead of reporting failure because the difference is exceeds 0? Second, why would specifying .000000001 satisfy OP’s request to throw an error if even one digit is off? This would seem to allow the values to differ by that amount.

Comment: The "delta" argument here is normally called *epsilon* and it's the magnitude of difference you're prepared to accept. A delta of 0 means "no difference at all" while a delta of 0.1 means a difference of up to 0.1. That is the absolute value of the difference must be less than or equal to the epsilon value. See also [why floats can be tricky](https://bitbashing.io/comparing-floats.html).

Comment: @tadman: If that comment was intended for me, I do not see how it answers my questions. Per the documentation, the OP’s `$this->assertEquals(17.2222222222000, 17.2222222222999)` **should** report an error because the two numbers differ by more than the delta, which is the default zero in this case. But the OP’s question says it passes, and they want it to report an error. So, first, why did it pass? Second, why would making the delta larger (going from zero to non-zero) cause the `assertEquals` to report an error? Increasing the delta makes the assertion more lax, not stricter.

Comment: FYI - the answer is now outdated due to changes on PHPUnit.  See Daniel Morell's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298451/2883328  

And also 
https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertequals
https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertequalswithdelta

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of PHPUnit (I am using PHPUnit 9.5 and it isn't there) no longer have the `$delta` parameter on `assertEquals` (same goes for `assertSame`).

You'll need to roll your own comparison with deltas, like this:

```
$this->assertLessThan(0.0000001, abs($expectedValue - $actualValue));
```

You may adjust `0.0000001` to your preferred delta tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

Since PHPUnit 7.5 you can use `assertEqualsWithDelta()` See [PHPUnit  issue #3340](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3340) for the details. It takes a delta as the third argument.

```
$this->assertEqualsWithDelta(17.2222222222000, 17.2222222222999, 0.00000001);
```

You can also read the [`assertEqualsWithDelta()` documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertequalswithdelta).